# Angular syntax: how do I get a list from a larger array for ng-repeat? -- Newbie

Tags: angularjs, syntax, angularjs-ng-repeat

Beginner question!
I've got an array of form

```
$scope.myArray['a'] = ['abc', 'def', 'etc'];
$scope.myArray['b'] = ['bbc', 'bef', 'btc'];
...
```

I want to use ng-repeat to present
abc
def
etc

So far, so good.  The problem is that I want to use an object obj.something as an index in the ng-repeat.  What is the correct syntax?  I tried:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in myArray.obj.something">  
<li ng-repeat="x in myArray(obj.something)">
<li ng-repeat="x in myArray[obj.something]">
<li ng-repeat="x in myArray{obj.something}">
<li ng-repeat="x in someFunction(obj.something)">
```

And so on.  What's the correct syntax or way to do this?

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/3uGOA6G2XisBprnfp2MB?p=preview

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output DOM you are expecting?

Comment: Is `obj.something` defined on the scope?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't really working with an array since javascript does not have associative arrays. What you have is an object literal

```
{    
    a: ['abc', 'def', 'etc'],
    b: ['bbc', 'bef', 'btc']    
}
```

If you just wanted to loop over `a` array with `ng-repeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in myArray.a">{{x}}</li>
```

If wanted to loop whole object

```
<li ng-repeat="(k, arr) in myArray">
      <h3>My Key is: {{k}}</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="item in arr"> {{item}}</div> 
</li>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/aPwg3KbRlsBdGqpc6W6x)**</kbd>

Comment: But please remember my question.  You refer to myArray.a.  Remember that instead of "a" I have "obj.something".  What is the syntax to use?  I can't use myArray.obj.something.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: have no idea what you have....please show it as you have it in your data by updating question `obj.something` isn't clear

Comment: I tried to give you something to follow.... if not familiar with objects and arrays...perhaps angular isn't for you. Requires good knowledge of how they work, inheritance understanding also

Comment: I'm familiar with objects and arrays.  You're not reading the question.  In Javascript, I would be able to say, foreach myArray[obj.something].  What is the syntax for doing that in Angular?

Comment: am more than willing to help but you are making it very difficult by not providing examples. Creat a demo... you get demo's when you ask for help, no reason you can't do the same. It is not entirely clear what you want..Yes I read The Question...and also asked for  more info

Comment: I think this will clarify it for you: I could write "temp=obj.something; myArray.temp" and get the array I want, but I can't do that within ng-repeat.

Comment: OK, I'll figure out Plunker, I haven't used it before.

Comment: Yes, very easy :)  Here's the plunk.  http://plnkr.co/edit/3uGOA6G2XisBprnfp2MB?p=preview